# Uploading files to S3 in Multithreading

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm uploading files to s3 using the s3 AWS client in my spring application, but sometimes I'm getting the error,

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
```

So as a solution to this I used the following approach and it worked for now.

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 s3Client() {
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration()
                    .withMaxConnections(100)
                    .withConnectionTimeout(100)
                    .withMaxErrorRetry(5))
            .build();
}

public String uploadFile() {
    // upload code
}
```

I have created this as a Spring Bean. But I am using this in a multithreading environment. So there will many concurrent requests at the same time. I see that `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` is annotated with `@NotThreadSafe`. So I need to know is it okay to use this as a bean in multithreading or else shall I use the above block of code inside the same `uploadFile` method? Can anyone explain me the best way? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't share the actual code for the uploading procedure but I think your problems lies with that one. So, to answer your questions:

1. Regarding the `@NotThreadSafe`, you should not be worrying about this. What you use the builder for, is to create an instance of `AmazonS3` client. This process is done during Spring initialization which in turn means the the whole process is handled by a [single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510395/does-spring-publish-beans-in-thread-safe-manner) and thus is not affected by potential synchronization problems. Note that what this mentioned before is in regards to the `AmazonS3ClientBuilder`. The created `AmazonS3Client` object (created by invoking `AmazonS3ClientBuilder#build`) is marked as thread safe as you can see in the related [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java).
2. Regarding the problem you are experiencing. Unfortunately, without sharing the upload object logic there is no concrete way to understand the exact reason for it. However, I think that your problem stems from the fact that you are creating a number of concurrent upload requests that is higher than the configured max connection number. This is in turn will cause those requests to block, waiting for a connection from the http pool to be retrieved. If one cannot be retrieved in a timely manner, then the request will timeout (what you are experiencing). For more you can check the related issue [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1405), which outlines the same behavior you are getting, albeit for a download action.